# What is the Spring Web Equivalent of MVC.NET's @Html.Action Method?

Tags: java, .net, spring-mvc, razor

Let me preface this: I'm interested in learning Spring and I have a solid JSF and MVC.NET/Razor background.

I'm trying to get up to speed on the web side of things with Spring and I'm looking for something equivalent the the `@Html.Action` call from a Razor template. Basically I'd like to do this:

```
//Route
  http://myserver/url/{int} => returns <html><body>Url (int)</body></html>

//Example Code (Pseudo Razor)
@for(in i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  <tr>
     <td>@Html.Action("url", new { @id=i})</td>
  <tr>
}

//Output I'd like to see
...
  <tr>
    <td><html>... Url 1 ...</html></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><html>... Url 2 ...</html></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><html>... Url 3 ...</html></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><html>... Url 4 ...</html></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><html>... Url 5 ...</html></td>
  </tr>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been searching for this answer for the last week and I have a feeling my terminology is all wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring MVC does not have its own view rendering technology.  However, it provides integration with common Java based view renderers.  In the .NET world, we would most commonly use either regular ASP.NET templates or Razor templates for web pages to be served from a web application.  Similarly, in the Java world we have access to technologies such as JSP, JSTL, FreeMarker, Velocity, HTTL, Scalate, Mustache, Thymeleaf, JSF and many more.

The example you have posted is akin to calling a reusable code snippet from inside a template.  The exact substitute in the Java world is then dependent on the view technology you are using.  Some examples below:

---

#### FreeMarker

```
<#macro action id><html><body>Url ${i}</body></html></#macro>

<#list 1..5 as i>
<tr>
  <td><@action i /></td>
</tr>
</#list>
```

#### Velocity

```
#macro ( action $i )<html><body>Url $i</body></html>#end

#foreach ( $i in [1..5] )
<tr>
  <td>#action($i)</td>
</tr>
#end
```

#### Thymeleaf

```
<html th:fragment="action(i)"><body>Url ${i}</body></html>
```

#### JSP

You would have to create a tag library and expose a tag for this.  This is harder than the examples above because the tag is a Java class and is exposed using a tag library descriptor.  The tag class contains the HTML to render and therefore means that HTML code is scattered across JSP files and Java classes.

---

Hope this helps.  In case you need more information, it will be helpful to know which view technology you are using.

Comment: I'm actually fishing for the technology to use that is similar. I'm a rather experience JSF/Java developer but I'm looking for a request based framework that doesn't rely on a component based model. I think JSP is probably the most "accurate" model right now. I'm looking for something highly flexible but with enough helper methods that I could draw the results from another action into the model. (I realize I could write this from the ground up but I'm sure something exists!) What I'd like to avoid is an expression language abstraction if possible.

Comment: I would say that you should choose between FreeMarker, Velocity and Thymeleaf if you are looking for a gentle curve.  Thymeleaf is the most elegant and I use it for all my prototyping and experimental work.  However, I use FreeMarker exclusively at work because it is way faster than Thymeleaf.  You can check out [this performance comparison](http://www.slideshare.net/jreijn/comparing-templateenginesjvm).  If you feel adventurous, you can try out Mustache or Scalate, both of which are quite terse and offer good performance.

Comment: Thanks, that link was a very useful overview.